# What Maven profile is executed when no profile is specified via -P?

Tags: java, maven

I'm not familiar with Maven and am trying to figure out how it works on our existing project.

project and folder structure is basically

> A
>
> A\1
>
> A\2
>
> A\3

Inside each folder is a pom file. Each pom contains 1 or more defined profiles.
What I do not understand is with this command

> A>mvn install

How do all of the pom get executed and which profiles are being executed?

I don't see any tags marked with ***activebydefault***

Frustrated when I need to spend time learning at step 1 and build some projects but am forced to be at step 50 without anybody on the team that knows the first thing about Maven. Of course solutions are always due yesterday.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Maven docs for [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)? Also, it's entirely possible that no profile is active by default. However, to learn what is happening during your build, you can execute `mvn help:active-profiles`.

Comment: Thank you for both the link and the mvn command reference.

Comment: Executing the command *mvn help:active-profiles* provides this information.The following profiles are active:

 - main (source: external)
 - defaultProfile (source: external).............. These I'm assuming are part of the default functionality to Maven but does not tell me what it is doing. So much to learn so little time.

Comment: external means the profiles are set in maven settings.xml of your machine, check on your maven installation folder (mvn -version would print the Maven Home, if required), in the conf folder you will find the settings.xml file where profiles are defined.

Comment: Also, take in account not all tasks from a POM are contained within profiles. The root `<build>` section declares all the tasks to be done wether there is an active profile or not.

Comment: Good clarification @LittleSanti, indeed seems that this point wasn't clear either, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Elijah please consider accepting an answer (not necessary mine, this is not an auto-endorsement) if satisfied so that this question doesn't list any longer as unanswered in the questions list. Otherwise, please share any further doubt.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Now your answer is so perfect that I wish I could upvote it _again_... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can be specified in your POM, in your parent POM, in your settings. Hence, looking just at your POM file may not be enough.

Running `mvn help:active-profiles` would give you a list of all active profiles and from which source (pom or settings).
Running `mvn help:all-profiles` would give you a list of all available profiles, the active ones and from which source (pom or settings).

Running `mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=full-pom.xml` would provide you the full POM file (in the `full-pom.xml` generated file), as a merging of current pom, parent pom and settings. That would be the full source of true.

The structure you describe is for a multi-module maven project, which means `A` is the [aggregator](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) project (having packaging `pom`, its only delivery is a pom file, its only function is to provide the `modules` it will build).
However, beware that in Maven aggregation and [inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) are two different concepts, which are often used together: aggregation means I will build as part of my build all of my defined modules; inheritance means I will inherit configuration from my parent pom. As such, `A\1` may inherit profiles from project `A` if in the pom of `A\1` you will find `A` defined as `parent` (which is often the case, to have an aggregator which is also parent of all the defined modules).

Why to have an aggregator? To have a centralized build and location of correlated sub-projects while still keep a good separation of concerns across sub-modules. Moreover, as Maven best practices, a project should only generate one artefact, hence it might be the case to have a web application having logic in one module, war generation in another module, ear generation in yet another module, for instance.

Why to have inheritance? To have a centralized place where to set shared/common configuration, like profiles but also dependencies and [dependencies management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).

Lastly, it is a common misunderstanding and hence be also aware that:

- If a profile is active by default in Maven, it will be part of the default build. However, if you activate a profile via command line (via the `-P` option) you will then activate the requested profile but also and automatically deactivate the one which was active by default
- the mechanism above doesn't apply to profiles defined in the `settings.xml` of your maven installation (which are applied by default, if activated, to all the Maven builds on the concerned machine).

**Update** A further note on this answer leveraged by some comments: a Maven build is specified as part of the `build` section (a flow of plugins executions), which doesn't necessarily need profiles. Profiles are generally defined to add a further behavior to the build, but it is good practice to have a build building successfully regardless of any activable profile, that is, I don't have to know about the defined profiles to run your build, it's a core concept of maven, harmonization and convention over configuration: given a Maven project, I can always assume that simply `mvn clean install` would do the required magic.
For a list of common questions about starting with Maven, the official [Getting Started Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) already provides a good help.
Also check the [Profiles Pitfalls](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) of the official Introduction to Profiles for further guidance on profiles.

Comment: If all pom files contain a profile with the same name, does that mean, when you call the parent pom (A in this case) that all of the sub folder pom files with that name in their profiles will be executed or is it only the parent poms profile with that name? And if it does not then how would someone call the parent pom by profile name and a sub pom profile with a different name?

Comment: All will be executed then

Answer (score 2):

No profile is active unless you have one marked as activeByDefault.

Comment: Something has to be active does it not, because when executing mvn install it still builds something. I interpret "No profile is active" as that nothing should build but that is not the case so what exactly is this thing magically knowing how to do?

Comment: No.  No profile has to be active.  You can think of a profile as an overlay on top of the base POM.  The beauty here is the 'magic' of the Maven lifecycle.

Comment: @Elijah - So you do not read the documentation then you come asking for someone to do that for you and spoon feed you the answers without any comprehension then you feel you can argue with their answers?

Comment: Not arguing with any answer.  I'm stuck in a BS environment with zero support.  I need to be at like 1 year solid knowledge on this stuff but am at day 1. Can not run any tutorials here because we're disconnected.  Not allowed to download any software.  Option is to go figure or or on my own time again with no support from work. Ifi knew what exactly I needed to ficus on I'd focus on it but not knowing what I don't know makes it a bit more of a challenge.